# How long should a Shiraz age?

Tags: wine, aging

I made a Shiraz from a kit early this spring (bottled in April). I also made a Johannesburg Riesling. I know reds take longer than whites to age, but we've been enjoying the Riesling for some time now (I have only one bottle left), while when I opened a Shiraz last week it was clearly not ready yet. Has anyone else done a Shiraz? How long did it take before it was good? How long before it was in its prime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's honestly a matter of taste. A lot of wines are good young.

A younger shiraz (3 months aging) is going to be pretty fruity and very bright tasting. Something reminiscent of a Beaujolais nouveau, just a little deeper.

At the six month mark some of that frutiness will dial down and blend in with more of a floral aroma/taste.

Year old shiraz tends to be more intensified. The flavors become more focused and lean hard on dark/dried fruit notes.

So once again. It just kind of depends on how you like your shiraz.